# css, disabled css files

Tags: css

how disables CSS file?

I use CMS and in header load style.css file. O don't have permission change index.php file, so i must change only in my file.

Thanks

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. You want to disable the whole style sheet?

Comment: Which files do you have access to? and why do you want to disable it? The was which requires the least permissions is simple to override the styles with new ones using `!important`. If you want no styles at all you could try doing this with a "css reset".

Answer (score 2):

Comment the whole css out. Start with /* and don't put the end piece in the file.

```
/*

// Here starts your normal css file
body {
    font-family: serif;
    ...
{
...

// Post at the end or not at all
*/
```

Comment: Why serve all that content if it isn't gonna be used?

Comment: You can delete the whole content, but when you need it back it's gone. Create a backup, of course, but my feelings say this is just for a temporary solution. But eventually, you're correct.

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying you don't want to use the stylesheet but can't remove it from the html markup?  If so, just delete everything in the file.  You can comment it all out, but if you're not using it, save the bandwidth and just erase the content.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace style.css with an empty style.css file.